# What does "all-new episode" mean?

Tags: production, terminology

Quite often, (maybe more often a few years ago than now) on an ad for a TV programme, the announcer will say something like, "Tonight: An all-new episode of *The Simpsons*!"

My question is, what does **all**-new mean? How can you have a partially new episode? The only thing I can think of is that they are telling us it won't be a clip show, which is faint praise at best.

Comment: It means completely original. The purpose isn't to distinguish it from "partially" new. Its just a marketing term to make it sound more appealing.

Comment: This was asked months ago and then closed as it is a common marketing expression that has been in use for decades.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/meaning-of-all-new-in-advertising-speak

Answer (score 3):

All-New Episode == Not a repeat. Never previously broadcast [on this network, at least.]

Really, it's marketing-speak, over-emphasis.

As there are now almost enough Simpsons episodes to be able to watch one a day for two years without seeing the same one twice, a way of ensuring the audience is aware that they have not seen this one before.

Answer (score -2):

An episode that it ALL-new. Not a single part of it was broadcasted, there is no content from previous episodes. 
It's a statement that deny that episode is a clip show.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClipShow

In the context of Simpsons it's very marketing move to prented that content in the episode (not only animation but jokes, story is new). Even Matt Groening made fun of "did I've seen this episode before" by making one of the Futurama screens like this 
[image]

Like Tetsujin answered, it's to make people aware that the epidose is brand new. It's just the jokes that are reused (as a person who suffer from hypermemory it happen very often).

Comment: is your account hacked or something? this doesn't feel like you

Comment: @Vishwa A hard case of "new keyboard who dis? said brain to fingers".